Confusion with two types of differential signal coupling
I'm having difficulty to articulate the question. But perhaps I might get close to it by an example.
I know that in differential signaling, both the signal and the receiving amplifier can be in various forms. But I sometimes saw sensors(such as a force sensor) or devices which has only two outputs where outputs couple to the inputs of a diff. or instrumentation amplifier; or I encountered some type of three terminal devices which has two bipolar signal outputs and a ground.
Below I tried to depict what I'm trying to say:

In Type 1 a sensor(like a thermocouple with only two terminals) is coupled to a diff amplifier as a balanced way(Z1=Z2).
In Type 2 a sensor(like a strain gauges in Wheatstone bridge configuration) is coupled to a diff amplifier again as a balanced way(Z1=Z2).
In Type 1, the system ground is diff. amplifier ground and the sensor has no such common ground with the amplifier.
In Type 2, the system ground is diff. amplifier ground and the sensor has a common ground with the amplifier.
My question is:
What's the main difference between the two in real life scenario? And is there any benefit in Type 2 having a common ground with the amplifier/system? Or is there any disadvantage(in terms of dealing with interference or ect.) in Type 1 having no common ground with the amplifier/system? This confuses me a lot so any knowledge related in answers I would very much appreciate.
(such as which one is better at rejecting noise or CM interference ect.)

You're on the right track as far as intuition, just need some gaps filled in I think.
How differential is an amplifier, really?
Very few circuits are truly differential, i.e. completely and utterly independent of Vcm, for all magnitudes and at all frequencies.
Also we already need definitions, because "completely and utterly" might be taken to mean here: for amplitudes pushing the breakdown of air (or other dielectric filling the system in question), or frequencies and amplitudes literally melting the enclosure/dielectric/etc., is the CMRR such that output levels are below the noise floor.
And yes, this is an extreme case, but true linearity does not care about magnitude: it works at 1nV or 1GV equally as well!  Clearly this is impossible (if nothing else, space itself breaks down into a black hole, given enough energy density!), so we know that linearity can only and ever be an approximation in practice, and thus we must have a limiting range over which that approximation remains valid.
For the more pedestrian case, like the differential amplifier circuit, or instrumentation amp or whatever, we are pretty strictly limited by the input voltage range (CMR, Vicm) of the amplifiers in question.  CMRR is limited by balance of resistors used (when applicable), and internal imbalance in the amplifiers.  For isolated amplifiers, range is generally the breakdown voltage, and CMRR is given by the isolation capacitance, shielding of the amplifier, and other quirks of the circuit.
Note that amplifier imbalance generally worsens as frequency rises, more or less because of trace imbalance in capacitances, and that as frequency rises, loop gain falls, therefore the ability to compensate for CM error by feedback action also falls.  Op-amp CMRR and gain plots have very similar shape for this reason.
Thus, an amplifier is differential only within its operating range, and only as good as the total CMRR of the system.  In general, we expect CMRR, and DM gain, to fall precipitously when Vicm is exceeded -- clipping or other distortion occurs, so we must stay within the Vicm range to expect nominal CMRR.
EMI
The other part missing, is a model of EMI.  There are three important cases:

Conducted noise, low frequency.  This can be conducted along cables (includes resonances due to cables acting as transmission lines over ground plane or through space), capacitively coupled from nearby surfaces or conductors, or magnetically coupled from nearby loops.
Conducted noise, high frequency.  This works the same as above, but transmission line effects cannot be ignored: in general, every wire in space acts as an antenna.
Transients: coupled by the above mechanisms, surges of quite large amplitude (some kV) and varying rate (from ms to ns) can be induced into the equipment.  These occur intermittently, so complete immunity might not be necessary -- but you probably don't want it causing a persistent upset, or outright damage.  And if you are receiving critical/high-priority signals, you may need quite a bit more filtering, CMR and CMRR than you would otherwise.

Thus we must expand the circuit at AC, considering loops such as capacitance from nearby elements, and magnetic induction.

Applying both of these principles to your circuits, we draw some ideas:

The first one is wholly susceptible to electric-induced (capacitive coupling) noise.  That is, at some limiting amplitude, CMR will be violated, and further issues develop.  Coupling is only attenuated by the amplifier's input CM impedance, and its CMRR while within range.  This works best for short lengths, where little induction is expected, and at low bandwidth where generous filtering can be applied.
Note that filtering will generally lower the CM impedance at AC, which itself helps with rejection.  But beware, the filter generally won't be well balanced in the transition band -- even if you spring for 5% capacitors, that's an average ~5% imbalance or -26dB DM-CM coupling -- so the EMI filter, and input diff amp BW, should generally be chosen well above the required signal bandwidth.

The second one has a ground reference (or something approximating it: note a resistance bridge has some CM resistance from excitation/common to signal pair), which can be combined into a cable, especially a shielded one, shunting induced current around the pair.  Whereas, if it's a multiconductor cable, you have to treat all pairs as differential still... now they're differential to each other, you have three pairings to consider, and the EMI concerns of the first case apply but in an even more complicated fashion.  Yuck!


There is a secret 3rd case:

The signal doesn't have to be balanced in the cable.  It helps, particularly for AC signals, but isn't very meaningful at low frequencies.
Note that every connection will have resistance, but we can have Z3 be the shield of a two-wire shielded cable, sinking ambient electric fields at least, but also we can join the diff(-) line to it at the far end, and now the diff pair is immune to induction (for frequencies above the shield cutoff frequency; typically 10s kHz to single MHz), Vicm is fixed to GND (or whatever voltage reference we care to apply), and we're still reading the differential signal at the device just as needed, no interference from Z3 voltage drop (and Z1 and Z2 in general are coupled to Z3's AC voltage drop).  This allows quite high bandwidth over long distances, with good rejection/immunity.
For something like a thermocouple, because bandwidth is very low (single Hz would be fast; there are some applications that go faster, but you'll be doing serious work to do it), a shield isn't important, and just brute-force filtering it down handles everything.  As long as there's no accidental (galvanic, LF/DC) sneak path to GND along the line that would create a loop (and imbalance), one side can be trivially grounded, and a single-ended amplifier used, no problem.
There's also a "secret first case", where the source is unbalanced -- coaxial, low frequency, and ground loop is involved.  This is a standard problem in analog audio, and the notorious ground loop has left users and engineers flummoxed for ages.  Well, as it turns out, a simple resolution exists: read the signal with a differential amplifier, as you normally would; terminate the shield to ground for EMI purposes, but allow it to float at audio frequencies, breaking the ground loop.  A modest input range (say ±10V) will suffice for most ground loop circumstances, and filtering above 100kHz or so will keep audio CMRR acceptable while rejecting EMI effectively.  (EMI in an audio context tends to lead to signal rectification: if you've ever heard a microphone or stereo pop-dit-beep-beeping from nearby cellphone communications, you've experienced an audio system with objective EMI issues.  The typical mechanism is rectification at amplifier input junctions, such as ESD clamp diodes, or particularly for BJT amp types, the input B-E junction.  Modulated RF is detected as a varying baseline value, i.e., an input offset, that's varying right in the audio band.)
